# Перестали отрываться jar-файлы ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, openjdk

Раньше по двойному клику открывалось gui приложение на **OpenJDK Java 8 Policy Tool**. Не знаю что случилось, но стало запускаться только из консоли. Разрешение на выполнение файла как программы стоит.

Comment: Правой кнопкой на .jar -> properties -> open with -> выбрать jre.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica ничего не происходит

Comment: И никаких ошибок?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica никаких

Comment: Я даже пробовал удалить http://ubuntu.fliplinux.com/java-2.html и заново установить java sudo apt-get install default-jdk, но всё равно

Comment: Ну, в общем, когда я удалил полностью Java, или я так думал, потом установил перестало даже из консоли запускаться Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found